# Row filter conversion to string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Im trying to use rowfilter in c# to match all the columns to a string, but the source column(Req Start Date) is in datetype.

```
 dvjan.RowFilter = "[Req Start Date]='January'";
```

How would i convert the type in rowfilter to get all dates that fall in january to show. I need to use the string "January'

I cant add comments for some reason, but this is for 1 year

Comment: For just one year or is this across multiple years?

Comment: @stefan, see my edit on how this can be achieved with RowFilter

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make both parts of a comparison string of the same format. In order to that, the best approach would be to get numeric month from string, you can do it like this:

```
int month = DateTime.ParseExact("January", "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month;
```

DataView is not really designed to work with dates. (You still can use dates with "#" delimiters, but here's a linq version that is performed on `datatable`

```
  var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("MyDate", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2011,1,10));
        dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2011,2,10));

        int month = DateTime.ParseExact("January", "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month;
        var list = dt.AsEnumerable()
                     .Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MyDate").Month == month)
                     .Select(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MyDate")).ToList();
        foreach (var d in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d);
        }
```

Edit:  If you want to work with dataview, you can specify upper and lower bounds.  like this:

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[MyDate] > #" + filterDateLower + "# and [MyDate] < #" + filterDateUpper +"#";
```

Full example:

```
var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("MyDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2012,1,10));
            dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2012,2,10));

            int month= DateTime.ParseExact("January", "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month;
            DateTime filterDateLower = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month, 1);
            DateTime filterDateUpper = filterDateLower.AddMonths(1);
            dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[MyDate] > #" + filterDateLower + "# and [MyDate] < #" + filterDateUpper +"#";
            foreach (DataRow d in dt.DefaultView.ToTable().Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d["MyDate"].ToString());
            }
```

Comment: thats seems more complex then needed, im looking for somwthing to convert it to a string and jsut match the month strings together.   dvjan.RowFilter = "(CONVERT(Req Start Date,System.String)='September'";

Comment: but the above doest work, how would i just convert the date time to a string.?

Comment: @stefan, the Convert you're trying to do won't take into consideration a year. You said that you only need the current year.

Comment: the source data is only contains 1 year.